# T4 iterate over projects in solution folders

Tags: visual-studio, project, t4, solution

I have a T4 template which generates my fluent builder classes for my api-contracts.  So when i have a contract CreatePersonRequest which has a name and a firstname, i generate a CreatePersonRequestBuilder which makes the CreatePersonRequest.

This way my builders are always up to date and by inheriting one of these I can make easily various pre-filled objects with a nice syntax.

This works fine when my projects are all located in root of my solution.  Once i started to add some solution folders, this didn't work anymore.

```
public EnvDTE.Project GetProjectByName(string projectName) {

    var serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)this.Host;

    var dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));



    var solution = dte.Solution;

    foreach (Project p in solution.Projects)

    {

        if (p != null) {

            if (p.Name == projectName){

                return p;

            }

        }

    }



    return null;

}
```

I retrieve all my projects from my solutions in the beginning and then iterate over these and verify the name.  Apparantly the word 'project' here can also means solution folder.

Pretty easy fix I thought.  Check the kind of the project (can be a project/folder/....) and in case of a folder go deeper into the ProjectItems hierarchy.

The problem I now have is that I have ProjectItem which is an interface (and not implemented by Project).  So I have no way to convert this ProjectItem to a Project (altough the ProjectItem.Kind property tells me it is a Project).

How can i retrieve projects deeper into the Solution hierarchy?